# Reuse SqlConnection from DbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlconnection

I need to use a `SqlConnection` to perform an untyped native sql query using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`. I have an existing DbContext instance available, which is used by some EF code inside the same transaction as the SqlConnection above. At the moment, I create a new SqlConnection, passing in the connection string from the DbContext:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
```

However, I dont think this is very efficient as it uses a second underlying connection to the DB, and because it is all in a transaction which involves a 2nd db connection (used by the DbContext EF code), it promotes the TX to using the DTC.

I would like to make a `SqlConnection` that reuses the same underlying DB connection as that used by the DbContext EF code. This avoids creating / using a 2nd db connection and avoids the need for the DTC. Is this possible? Is this good practice?

EDIT: I tried this code:

```
private List<T> UseReader<T>(DbContext db)
    {
        try
        {
            var connection = (db.Database.Connection) as SqlConnection;

            connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);

            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            ...
```

but it complained that the connection was not open. So then I changed the code to this:

```
    private List<T> UseReader<T>(DbContext db)
    {
        if( db.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open )
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
        }

        try
        {
            var connection = (db.Database.Connection) as SqlConnection;


            connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);

            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            ..
```

And then I started getting this error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached
```

So finally I tried this code:

```
    private List<T> UseReader<T>(DbContext db)
    {
        var opened = false;

        if( db.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open )
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            opened = true;
        }

        try
        {
            var connection = (db.Database.Connection) as SqlConnection;


            connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);

            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            if (opened)
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
        }


    }
```

But that led to this error appearing in downstream EF code:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the `DbContext` has been disposed
```

EDIT 2: Solution - the final version of the code was correct actually. The reason I was received the error regarding the disposed `DbContext`, was because in our previous investigations we had included a `SqlConnection.ClearPool()` call somewhere downstream, which started throwing that error after including the `connection.close()` call.

Comment: You cant create a new `SqlConnection` that **is** another connection. You either reuse it or create a new one. To reuse just use `db.Database.Connection` directly (*but obviously do not put it in a `using` block*).

Comment: Hi, please see my edit above - I've tried what I think you're suggesting, but  getting new errors

Comment: 1) You can only use the DbContext in the lifetime scope of that DbContext. If you dispose of it then you cant use the connection. 2) You cant close the connection of the DbContext, when you are done with the connection AND the DbContext then dispose of the DbContext.